# Lightning Overlay library access attribute issues

Tags: lightning-aura-components, release, lightning-overlaylibrary

I have managed package where we are using lightning:overlayLibrary to render the modals, we've installed our package in many customers org.

We've followed our best practices to specify access attributes to aura:attributes which supports **access**.

After the salesforce recent release i'm seeing the following exception when i tried to open any tab where we have overlayLibrary used component included i'm seeing the following exception:
[image]

When i started digging deeper, i'm able to figure it out the root cause of the exception, in the recent release salesforce removed the access attribute for **lightning:overlayLibrary** tag

But why salesforce is deprecated the access attribute without giving any head's up, Even they didn't provide any information on [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:overlayLibrary/specification). To solve that issue again i need to push the changes.

Comment: Where did you find the access `attribute` and its usage. Have not seen any querstion or answer having it. Using unsupported attributes may tend to break. Could you please edit your question and add some code for getting better support.

Comment: @Raul, if the attribute is not available in the developer guide, how it will allow me to save the code? Now i updated my code and released new version, i don't have any old references, even there is not last updated date in documentation